# Maven repository solo Local

Tags: maven

pasa que estoy usando maven, tengo configurado 1 repositorio  en mi archivo pom, para que en caso que alguna dependencia no sea encontrada en mi M2, la busque en ese repositorio, pero  me pasa que, aunque tenga agregados los jar en mi M2, maven no los busca y directo se va a buscar a repositorio fuera del local.

Config en pom para repositorio:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>xxxxx</id>
      <name>archiva</name>      
      <url>http://xx.xx.xx.xx/repository/internal/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

¿Conocen una forma de evitar que maven busque en otro repositorio que no sea el local m2?

Comment: La situación que describes es extraña. Maven siempre busca por defecto en tu repositorio local (la carpeta .m2 que dices), luego en los repositorios indicados y luego en los repositorios oficiales. ¿Estás seguro que no has cambiado el group id, artifact id o la versión de los componentes que necesitas?

Comment: No, de hecho tengo todas las dependencias en mi repositorio local, por lo cual no deberia ir al repositorio indicado y tomarlas del repositorio local,  lo cual no pasa, pues ejecuto el  mvn clean install, y de  inmediato se va a bsucar al repositorio configurado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la opción **`-o`** que hace referencia a *`offline`*, esto forzará a maven a buscar las dependencias solo en el repositorio local. Ejemplo:

```
mvn clean install -o
```